# Excel Calculate Average and Median across multiple worksheets and columns

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for some Excel help. I have the following worksheets:

```
WORKSHEET WEEK1
A-------|B------|C------|D------
NAME    |GAME A |GAME B |GAME C
JIM      10      15      12
BILL     12      10      5
TED      
PHIL     0       8       17

WORKSHEET WEEK2
A-------|B------|C------|D------
NAME    |GAME D |GAME F |GAME B
JIM      15      10      9
BILL     
TED      3       21      18 
PHIL     12      2       30
```

Basically, I'll have 10 worksheets (one per week). We are tracking people's pinball scores over a series of weeks. The games/scores will NOT be in the same order on the sheet week after week (20 machines, only six played per week).

I need to calculate Average and Median for the machine across multiple worksheets, AND eliminate any missing or zeroed scores (so the average of 10,0,10 is 10, same for median, same for data missing/null).

I used this for the first week

```
=MEDIAN(IF('1B'!L:L>0,'1B'!L:L))
```

And seemed to be just ducky, but am struggling getting this to be cross sheet in varied columns excluding blanks.

I'm not opposed to having another sheet that looks through all of the worksheets and columns to find a match on the game title and then grab that column, calculate, done. But if I have to do this manual-ish, that's totally not a problem.

I'm a C# developer, so I get code, I'm just dreadfully bad at Excel and the syntax makes me the tiniest bit sad.

UPDATE:
The expected output is as follows:
    GAME A: Average: X, Median Y
    GAME B: Average: Z, Median N

Thanks much!

Comment: So can you give a couple of examples of expected results for the data you posted? Also, might be an idea to give us an idea of the layout of the results table that you've set up to house the results.

Comment: Certainly, and thanks!

All I'm looking for for the results is:

SCORE A: Avg: 12 Median 13
SCORE B: Avg: 9 Median 11

(this math is wrong, hopefully you get the idea).. It's basically each pinball machines Average and Median throughout the N weeks it's in play. 

All I need is the info, that will be taken out of Excel into another program

Comment: I see. So these are not refined further by name?

Comment: Let's say there are three machines, and each week we play two. All I'm looking for is something like this: BATMAN: AVG: 12,365,220 MED: 14,252,100 ||| TRON: AVG: 6,329,200 MED: 9,234,532. In the original post, consider SCOREA = BATMAN, SCOREB = TRON

Comment: Additionally, I'm okay with having that separate sheet have 20 different formulas (for the 20 different machines) that I manually adjust as the weeks go by with that machines new sheet and whatever column it is to appear in

Comment: I'm afraid you've just confused me with this new talk of  BATMAN, TRON, etc. What has this to do with  SCOREA, SCOREB, etc.? When I asked whether these results were to be refined by name, I was referring to TIM, BILL, TED, etc. All of this is why I suggested that you should add your blank results table to the post, with perhaps a couple of expected results added.

Comment: SCOREA in the table above is a pinball machine. Like TRON. I don't care about any of the individual people, I'm looking for average and median scores across the machine, not the player. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1) You have `Excel 2007` or later

2) The data in each of the sheets to be queried occupies the range `A1:D5` (with headers in row 1 and names in column A)

3) You put your choice of game (e.g. "GAME B") for which you wish to obtain the desired results in cell `A1` of a sheet other than those being queried

First go to `Name Manager` (`Formulas` tab) and make the following definition:

Name: `SheetList`

Refers to: `={"Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"}`

(Or whatever happen to be the relevant sheet names in question.)

The required `array formula**` for the average is then:

`=AVERAGE(IFERROR(1/(1/N(INDIRECT(SheetList&TEXT(ROW(B2:D5)*10^5+TRANSPOSE(MODE.MULT(IF(T(INDIRECT(TRANSPOSE(SheetList)&TEXT(10^5+COLUMN(B2:D5),"!R0C00000"),0))=A1,COLUMN(B2:D5)),COLUMN(B2:D5))),"!R0C00000"),0))),""))`

Replace `AVERAGE` with `MEDIAN` in the above to obtain the equivalent median for that game.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thanks for the reply @XOR LX. I am using Excel 2013. I've set the names, and have added that formula to the sheet, but am unable to get it to work. I think we're getting tripped up on what's going on here. I've uploaded my working spreadsheet here [link]http://www.alcohog.com/sample.xlsx[/link] and it might make a little more sense if you have a moment to take a look at it.

Comment: Can you check that link? I get the following message: " HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. "

Comment: The formatting got screwy, hopefully that one works! thanks Xor!

Comment: Can't seem to see your attempt at adding my solution anywhere in this file?

Comment: It's not in there, that's the original spreadsheet with the games/scores/averages information.. i wanted you to see the format of it to make sure we were on the same page because the descriptions seemed to be getting confused

Comment: Ah, if it's all the same I'd prefer you to have a stab at it first.

Comment: Can you look at the spreadsheet where I have the averages, and how they are being calculated based on the 4 weeks that are in and let me know if your formula still applies? I'm trying to understand what's going on with that formula itself, and not sure how this is determining (and isolating) the individual game names. 
Thanks for stickin' with this :)

Comment: Try adapting the solution I gave: amend ranges/worksheet names as required.